# ASUS Sabertooth Z77 + i7-3770K CPU LED Error

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, post

After two weeks and hours of testing, researching and stripping machine down to just board, psu and proc outside of box, I am still getting a CPU LED Error which is causing the unit to not post.  Before taking all other hardware out, it would power on, fans would power, drives etc.  it would stay powered until i did a hard shut down.  No beeps from speaker and no other LED Error lights.  The only non powered devices where the USB devices.  I also couldn't get signal to display from both on-board and video card.

After getting unit down to mobo, PSU and proc + 2 different coolers outside of case on cardboard, i still get the same results.  **Note: I have even RMA the motherboard to ASUS.  They took a week and sent it back with no notes or nothing.  I contacted support and they stated "We don't share the repair notes with the customer, but we did have it working.  Try resetting BIOS".  Obviously did that before sending it to them, again after words but 0 change**  I have tried nearly everything I can think of including:

1. Remounting proc with new paste
2. Checking socket with mag glass for bent pins
3. Proc in friends old board (lga1155 socket also) worked
4. Cleared CMOS (jumper, jumper + new battery)
5. BIOS flashback from usb (had to use the utility as i don't have a display because of the cpu error)
6. Checking all cables for plug issues or open wires etc
7. Had all components besides MOBO tested separately at a retail shop as they had all the proper equipment.  All worked fine.
8. Checked manual to ensure proc was compatible

I was working for about 4 months after i got the mobo new and stopped when I added a AIO cooler the graphics card.  But not right way, about another month after.  I have since removed the card and taken it out of the equation, but still have same results.

Can anyone please give me some ideas or call me out on something that I am missing?  I am losing hope after 2 weeks of constant failure.

Comment: The motherboard is running the current firmware?

Comment: It is/was.  is there a way to reset that similar to the bios on that board? (Where it can be updated even though the unit will not post)

Comment: If it cannot POST then you normally cannot upgrade or recover the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

According to Asus, that motherboard [needs BIOS version 0801 or higher](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/HelpDesk_CPU/) to work with that CPU.

If you're using an earlier version, you'll need to first update to 0801 (or newer).  The trick is you'll need a working CPU/system to be able to upgrade the BIOS to 0801 before you put the I7-3770 in.

Comment: So i used the USB bios flashback with bios SABERTOOTH Z77 BIOS 2104.  It did properly flash it (according to the manual).  That utility doesn't require anything but the mobo and power + usb with bios on it to flash.  I could try to take the cpu back to test it again, but it did work on a different machine 2 weeks ago.  maybe it was bios issue then, and i have since broken the cpu when transporting?  Thats gotta be a stretch though.

Comment: @WCEM2040 - Are you 100% the firmware you have currently is 2104?

Comment: Not to say it doesn't exist, but I've never seen a BIOS that can be flashed (even using emergency recovery) with a broken/incompatible CPU installed.  If you plug your friend's CPU (that works with your board) back in, does it report the expected BIOS version?

Comment: Two times certain.  downloaded, flashed, didn't fix issue. so i downloaded again, flashed and still the same.

Comment: Actually either did I until i found [USB BIOS FLASHBACK](http://event.asus.com/2012/mb/USB_BIOS_Flashback_GUIDE/) which gave me SO much hope.  my buddy has an lga1155 board, but not asus.  if i check the bios version on his it wouldn't match would it?

Comment: Take your friend's CPU and put it in *your* board, and check the revision reported by *your* BIOS. :)  Also, Asus' USB Flashback looks like it would do it without a CPU, but right there on the page: "System requirements: ASUS **X99 motherboard** featuring USB BIOS Flashback".

Comment: :) spare board, no proc.  I am currently searching for a test proc

Comment: Sorry, just linked to the newest page.  In the [Manual](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_Z77/HelpDesk_Download/) it gave me step by step instructions and requirements.  Any chance you think a bios version closer to 0801 would possibly work?  I know stupid idea, but i have yet to try it...

Comment: Ahh it says Proc *IN* friends old board, not *From*.. My bad. :/   Perhaps you should take the Motherboard to that same retail shop you had other parts tested at, and have them test it with known-good parts.  from my experiences (after many years reselling Asus motherboards, amongst others) their RMA department sucks. PS: they won't repair your board and send it back, they'll just send you one they pulled out of their "repaired" pile, hence why they won't/can't share specific repair notes (This is normal procedure for most companies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30324/discussion-between-wcem2040-and-c007).